impor telebot, @bot.poll_answer_handler() doesn't work
Poll answer does not work, that is, it is not even called, @bot.poll_answer_handler() , I think I tried everything, everything I was looking for is not there, it seems to me that this is some kind of bug already in my system, here is the code.
import telebot

API_TOKEN = "My token)"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
@bot.poll_answer_handler() 
def hadle_poll_answer(poll):
    print("Work!")
    print(poll)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["poll"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'chose', ['a', 'b'], is_anonymous = False)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["stop"])
def stop_bot(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "bye-bye")
    bot.stop_polling()

bot.polling()`

I tried to put a lambda function, but it doesn't work, maybe you need some kind of bot.poll_handler, or bot.poll_answer_handler, I don't know , example I found
`# This is an example file to create quiz polls
import telebot

API_TOKEN = "<api_token>"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["poll"])
def create_poll(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "English Article Test")
    answer_options = ["a", "an", "the", "-"]

    bot.send_poll(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        question="We are going to '' park.",
        options=answer_options,
        type="quiz",
        correct_option_id=2,
        is_anonymous=False,
    )


@bot.poll_answer_handler()
def handle_poll(poll):
    # This handler can be used to log User answers and to send next poll
    pass


bot.infinity_polling()

